# Programatically read all mails from NSF file without having lotus notes installed

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I want to programatically read all mails from .nsf file without having lotus notes installed. Does anyone know how to do that? Is there any 3rd party api.

Comment: There is no 3rd party API, and the terms of IBM's license for Notes plus the fact that IBM has many more lawyers than any conceivable 3rd party makes it very unlikely that there ever will be.  (There are technical reasons, too.)

Answer (score 3):

If the database is hosted on a server, then you can use the Java NCSO.jar (DIIOP) to access the database without Notes installed.

Otherwise, it is not possible without Notes.

Note that you can now get Domino Designer for free from IBM, As long as the application is used locally to the Designer client. If you plan to deploy the application in production then you need a license for Notes/Domino.

You can download Designer from here.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/dominodesigner/

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. If you want to use the Lotus Notes Api, you will have to install the Lotus Notes package and configure a user, because you have to validate the NotesID in installation and provide authentication against that id when using the API.

You start the Lotus Notes ID api like this:

```
    SesionLotus = new NotesSession();            
    SesionLotus.Initialize("Password");
    SesionLotus.ConvertMime = false;
```

This password, is going to validate against the ID of the working Lotus notes installation.

Answer (score 0):

Use REST Services! You only need the Domino administrator to open up the mail database in question for DDS (Domino Data Services) usage, and then you can use any programming technique with ability to use REST services. Take a look at [Domino Data Services](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino+Data+Service#action=openDocument&res_title=IBM_Domino_Data_Service_overview_dds10&content=apicontent) to get an idea how you can access Domino data via REST Services.